# how to wrap string containing dynamically loaded value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't see errors in my logic maybe You'll help Me

I've got this at the  moment

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var str = $('#formElements').text();
  str = str.slice(104,112);
  alert(str);
  $('#formElements:contains('+ str +')').load(function(){
   $(this).html().replace(str, '<div class="price-cal-check">'+str+' <span id="priceout"></span>zł</div>');
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  method="post" name="form" action="javascript:void(0);">
<div id="formElements" style="float:right; min-height: 280px; margin-left: 20px; width: 575px;">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Quantity:</td>
    <td>Paper type:</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input name="amount" value="1" type="text"></td>
    <td> <select name="paper">
          <option value="1">250 gsm</option>
         </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 
 Price: $
 
 <br>
 <input class="submitToCart" name="addCart" value="Add to cart" role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="margin-top: 4px;" type="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

the value of `<span id="priceout">27,00</span>` is generated dynamicaly after page loads with jQuery.

so he output of str looks like this `Price: $`

all i want to do is to put whole string `Price: <span id="priceout">27,00</span>$` in to div. but my code isn't work

what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to wrap the `price:` text in a `div` with an `ID` and target that instead

Comment: str contains `pe:` and there is no load event on a div and even if there were it was already triggered before your code runs

Comment: sorry my mistake I've repaired this with `str` on live code it's working a little bit different

Answer (score 1):

If it was up to me, I'd rather wrap that `Price:` in a div, give it an ID and then append it with the value like:

```
<div id="price"> Price: </div>
```

and in your function

```
$('#price').append('<span id="priceout">27,00</span>$');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't edit this element because it's generated on server and i have no access to this file, that's because I'm struggling with this jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found a solution now js looks like this

```
$('#formElements').each(function() {
            var form = $(this);
            var str = form.html();
            var str1 = str.slice(225,260);
            //alert(str);
            form.html(str.replace(str1,'<div class="price-cal-check">'+ str1 +'</div>'));
        });
```

and it works